# How to exclude an array of indexes from loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `y` like this:

```
var y = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

And I would like to iterate through the array, but exclude some indexes. The indexes are saved in second array

```
var x = [1,3];
```

So, I want to write each numbers from an array `y`, but not the numbers on the position 1,3, which come from array `x`

I tried to skip the numbers on these positions, but with no success. Could you please help me?
Here is what I tried

```
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            if (i === x[j]) {
        continue;
     } 
    }
 console.log(y[i]);
}
```

Comment: Cant you find better names than `x` and `y ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method.

```js
var list = [1,2,3,4];
var skipIndexes = [1,3]; 

for (var i = 0; i< list.length; i++) {
 if (! skipIndexes.includes(i)) {
  console.log(list[i]); 
 }
}
```

Comment: Should’nt it be console.log(list[i])?

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**

Prefer using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) over a loop

```js
const xs = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]  // array of values
const ys = [ 1, 3 ]           // indices to skip

// using `filter`
const zs = xs.filter((_, i) => !ys.includes(i))

console.log(zs)
//=> [ 1, 3, 5 ]
```

**Long answer**

When possible, you don't want to be using a loop because it can hurt the ability to understand your code taking a procedural approach over a declarative approach. You can instead use a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) like [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to keep the values you want. The return value of the function passed into `filter` needs to return a boolean of what to keep. In JavaScript, the `filter` function is of binary arity, meaning it takes two arguments, with the first argument being the array element and the second being the index. We can ignore the array element value as it is only the index we need to check (this is why the function starts with `(_, ...)` to drop the first argument).

[`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is a function on the array prototype that lets you know if the array contains a value (i.e. `[0].includes(0) === true` and `[0].includes(1) == false`).

Putting these two concepts together, we can iterate over the first array, `xs`, ignoring the values but using the index to see if it's included in our blacklisted indices array, `ys`.

If we looked at this as a `map` function, instead of `filter` that included our value

```
xs.map((v, i) => [ v, !ys.includes(i) ])
//=> [ [ 1, true ], [ 2, false ], [ 3, true ], [ 4, false ], [ 5, true ] ]
```

We can see which values will be `true`. And if we remember, filter keeps our `true` values `[ 1, 3, 5 ]`.

Comment: This is a good answer - but you should perhaps explain how it works.

Comment: ^ You might as well write a full snippet to demonstrate that it works.

Comment: @Thomas no, OP said the other array is indices not values

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you were pretty close, but you don't need the inner loop. Just check if the index you're on (`i`) is one of the members of the array `x`, and if so, continue. You can do that using the array `.includes` method, or `indexOf` if you don't have es6 support.

```js
var y = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var x = [1,3];

for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
    if (x.includes(i)) continue; // Or if not es6 use: `x.indexOf(i) !== -1`
    console.log(y[i]);
}
```

This prints `1` and `3`, which are the items of the array `y` in the `0`th and `2`nd indices respectively (since we skipped indices 1 and 3).